# Not able to import speech_recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I have installed SpeechRecognition and PyAudio successfully (using pip), but whenever I try to import speech_recognition it spits out this error:

```
Unable to import 'speech_recognition' pylint(import-error)
```

Comment: What code are you using to import the module?

Comment: `import speech_recognition`

Comment: Check this similar problem https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/272#issuecomment-349243765

Answer (score 0):

To ensure `python3 -m speech_recognition` if you were installed by pip3, or `python -m speech_recognition` if using pip correctly working.

The other hand, ensure you using correct interpreter who has been installed `speech_recognition`

Answer (score 0):

I have done a project that required this. What I did was

import speech_recognition as sr

Then I used sr for my purpose. Try to use sr as speech recognition for whatever your project is.